# SQL - Expand column of arrays into column of elements

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, data-science

I have a SQL table, and one column of the table has type text[]. I want to create write a query that will create a new table, which consists of all arrays flattened and concatenated. Ex: If there are 3 items in the table, and the array entry for each of those items is [1, 2, 3], NULL, [1, 4, 5], I want the result set to be [1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5].

[UNNEST](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays) seems like it could be useful here. But, I can't find a way to apply the function to every array in the table. Essentially, I want to "map" this function over every row in the table. Can anyone point me in a good direction?

```
CREATE TABLE arrs (
  col1 int,
  col2 text[]
);


INSERT INTO arrs (col1, col2) VALUES (1, '{"a", "b", "c"}');
INSERT INTO arrs (col1, col2) VALUES (2, '{"d", "e"}');
```

I want the query to return a table with 5 rows with text values "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" for the above table.

Useful REPL for testing: https://replit.com/languages/sqlite

Thanks!

Comment: *one column of the table has type **string[]*** No such datatype in MySQL. Check your DBMS carefully and edit tags list accordingly.

Comment: @Akina - sorry, meant text[]. Just edited.

Comment: No difference. ***text[]*** not exists in MySQL too.

Comment: @Akina correctly updated tag from MySQL to postgresql. Sorry for mistake!

Comment: Provide a sample (CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, 3-5 rows) and desired output for this data.

Comment: @Akina just provided, thanks for your attention

Comment: I see the words about NULL values presence but do not see it in the script. And I don't see desired output. The most first question - does the elements order makes sense and must be saved? both in separate source array and in concatenated array (order by `col1`?).

Comment: @Akina the accepted answer works with null values (i.e., it acts like an empy list) because of the functionality of unnest. The order of elements does not matter for my use case.

Comment: Why are you referring to the manual of Google BigQuery if you are using Postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just expand all the arrays in the table (with `UNNEST`) and put into one common array (with `ARRAY_AGG`):

```
with t as (select unnest(col2) as elems
from arrs)
select array_agg(t.elems)
from t;
```

Here's [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6d0d3e2f29c2d00e305371eb664fd21b) also